# Javascript ReferenceError: function is not defined but it is

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I have checked the code, but I can't find anything wrong.

```
<!-- language: lang-html -->

<div class="modal fade" id="loginModal" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <!-- Modal content-->
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div id="loginHeader" class="modal-header">
                <h4 class="modal-title">Oops, something not right.</h4>
            </div>
            <div id="loginContent" class="modal-body" runat="server">
            </div>
            <div id="loginButton" class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning" data-dismiss="modal">OK</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <button type="button" style="display: none;" id="btnShowLoginModal" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#loginModal">
    </button>
</div>
<script src="../Scripts/javascripts/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="../Scripts/javascripts/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function ShowLoginDialog() {
        $("#btnShowLoginModal").click();
    }
</script>
```

The function is called from code behind on OnClick Event. Still no clue which part is wrong.

```csharp
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string result = ValidateLogin(Username.Value, Password.Value);

    if(result == MessageConstants.MessageSuccess)
    {
        Response.Redirect("~/Webpages/Character.aspx");
    }
    else if(result == MessageConstants.MessageFail)
    {
        ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), Guid.NewGuid().ToString(), "ShowLoginDialog()", true);
    }
    else
    {
        ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), Guid.NewGuid().ToString(), "ShowLoginDialog()", true);

    }
}
```

Error from Element Inspector
[image]

Comment: Where is it being called from? Please provide a [mcve]

Comment: Where are you using the function?

Comment: Where you call that function ??

Comment: You maybe invoking the function at the page's head?

Comment: Move the inline script (containing the function) before any other `script` tags, probably in the `head` tag.

Comment: The second code is for the server's HTML pre-processing, right? I don't know C#, but it is similiar to the lang.

Comment: @trincot i moved to the head tag but still the same

Comment: Show your runtime HTML through element inspector.

Comment: You should add a tag that describes the server-side programming environment you use. Maybe one of the `.net` tags.... This will attract the right people here.

Comment: The function is defined after the point at which it is called. Move the function definition into the head section of the document.

Comment: @KevinCollins i tried. still the same

Comment: Do NOT wrap the declaration of `ShowLoginDialog` in `$(document).ready(function() { ... })` like you have done in the screenshot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

RegisterStartupScript() emits the script block at the end of the Web Form (right before the `</form>` tag). [source](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa478975.aspx)

But your modal code, and the ShowLoginDialog function are defined after that. Try moving that `</form>` tag to the end, after the modal stuff.

Comment: thank you so much! it actually works when i move the script into the <form> tag.

Answer (score 0):

Put your code in the `document.ready()` function:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    function ShowLoginDialog() {
        $("#btnShowLoginModal").click();
    }
});
```

Comment: When you call that function, on page load or on any event ?

Comment: @SKJajoriya its actually OnClick event called that function

Comment: This will only make the issue worse because `ShowLoginDialog` will not be available on the global scope

Answer (score 0):

Move

```
<script src="../Scripts/javascripts/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="../Scripts/javascripts/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function ShowLoginDialog() {
        $("#btnShowLoginModal").click();
    }
</script>
```

into the `head` block. Then you need to change the `ShowLoginDialog` function so that it looks like this:

```
function ShowLoginDialog() {
    $(function() {
        $("#btnShowLoginModal").click();
    });
}
```